# Manga where the red haired female character went back to time to change her fate

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I forgot the title of this manga because it was in Japanese kanji. (Can't properly read it yet so I can't remember). So, the manga goes like this. The female protagonist somewhat suffered or something from her past life and died. (She was a priestess or a saint in that life). The FL came from a battle family (or swordsman family and she is like the 2nd daughter or first? and she has 2 older brothers who doesn't like her.) In her second life, she came back from her younger age or around her coming of age ceremony. Because she remembers her last life, she didn't wanted to become a saint but instead became a swordsman for the army. (She was the best one and even fought against the commander who has a long and dark colored hair). She achieve many things too.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like [Tensei shita Daiseijo wa, Seijo de aru koto wo Hitakakusu](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/tensei-shita-daiseijo-wa-seijo-de-aru-koto-wo-hitakakusu), also known as "A Tale of The Great Saint" or "The Reincarnated Great Saint Hides That She's a Saint".

> Fia always dreamed of becoming a knight. Born into a family of knights, she's the least talented among them, but she still clutches to her hope and trains with everything she has. ... she suddenly remembers her former life, when she was a powerful Saint in a bygone era who defeated the Demon King. That life ended in pain because of who she was, making her fear ever becoming a Saint again.

Specifically, as a saintess she was part of a party to defeat the demon lord, and he cursed her if she ever reincarnates. She retains her powers, but (mostly) avoids using them to not draw attention to herself. She focuses on using enchantment magic on herself and her weapons to allow her to enlist as a knight, which makes her stand out as the most talented recruit.